# GPG Keys Missing, Can't Be Found on Keyserver Either

Tags: ubuntu, gnupg

So this error has been popping up a lot so I thought I'd resolve it:

```
W: GPG error: http://cfengine.com precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 535C743689107B44
```

So I did some research and tried these solutions

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 535C743689107B44
```

and

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 535C743689107B44
```

both of which terminated with this message

```
gpgkeys: key 535C743689107B44 not found on keyserver
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Any insights are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the first step in the documentation...

http://cfengine.com/cfengine-linux-distros

> To install CFEngine using these repositories, follow these steps: For
>   Debian-based systems (apt):
>
> ```
> Download and install the CFEngine GPG key:
>
>
> # wget http://cfengine.com/pub/gpg.key
> # apt-key add gpg.key
> # rm gpg.key
> ```

Actually I could "fix the issue" for you :) CFengine key is now uploaded to `pgp.mit.edu`, so if you use that as a keyserver, it should work.